# F#: Updating a single tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: f#

I have a list of tuples like so:

```
let scorecard = [ for i in 0 .. 39 -> i,0 ]
```

I want to identify the nth tuple in it.  I was thinking about it in this way:

```
let foundTuple = scorecard |> Seq.find(fun (x,y) -> x = 10)
```

I then want to create a new tuple based on the found one:

```
let newTuple = (fst foundTuple, snd foundTuple + 1)
```

And have a new list with that updated value

Does anyone have some code that matches this pattern?  I think I have to split the list into 2 sublists: 1 list has 1 element (the tuple I want to replace) and the other list has the remaining elements.  I then create a new list with the replacing tuple and the list of unchanged tuples...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `List.mapi` which creates a new list using a specified projection function - but it also calls the projection function with the current index and so you can decide what to do based on this index.

For example, to increment second element of a list of integers, you can do:

```
let oldList = [0;0;0;0]
let newList = oldList |> List.mapi (fun index v -> if index = 1 then v + 1 else v)
```

Depending on the problem, it might make sense to use the `Map` type instead of list - map represents a mapping from keys to values and does not need to copy the entire contents when you change just a single value. So, for example:

```
// Map keys from 0 to 3 to values 0
let m = Map.ofList [0,0;1,0;2,0;3,0]
// Set the value at index 1 to 10 and get a new map
Map.add 1 10 m
```

Answer (score 0):

I went back and thought about the problem and decided to use an array, which is mutable.

```
let scorecard = [| for i in 0 .. 39 -> i,0 |]
```

Since tuples are not mutable, I need to create a new tuple based on the existing one and overwrite it in the array:

```
let targetTuple = scorecard.[3]
let newTuple = (fst targetTuple, snd targetTuple + 1)
scorecard.[3] <- newTuple
```

I am using the "<-" which is a code smell in F#.  I wonder if there a comparable purely functional equivalent?

Comment: `let scorecard = [('a', 0);('b', 1);('c', 2);('d', 3)]
let target = scorecard.[3]
let newTuple = (fst target, snd target + 1)
newTuple :: List.filter ((<>) target) scorecard`

Disrupts your order, idk if that matters